# NodeJS Net.createServer

Tags: node.js

Hey uh I am having an issue and I think this is probably related to net.createserver.

The issue is that whenever the first client joins after that another second client joins, the first client can control the second client and then the first client disconnects because the socket(end) event gets triggered. Is it related to sockets or something or the server can't handle two connections? Please help

The code:

```
    handleGame: function() {
    console.log(log.success('The source is starting!'));
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
        console.log('A client has connected' + "\r\n");
        socket.setEncoding('utf8')
        global.clientObjz = new client(socket);
        game.addClient(clientObjz);
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            data = data.toString().split('\0')[0];
            console.log('Incoming data: ' + data + "\r\n")
            if (data == "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'><ver v='153' /></body></msg>" | data == "<msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'></body></msg>" | data.startsWith("<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'>")) {
                parseXml(data, function(err, result) {
                    var type = result.msg['$'].t,
                        action = result.msg.body[0]['$'].action;

                    var method = Game.xmlHandlers[type][action];

                    if (typeof Game[method] == 'function') {
                        Game[method](data, client);
                    }
                });
            }
            var dataType = data.charAt(0);
            if (dataType == '%') {
                game.handleraw(data, clientObjz);
            }
        });
        socket.on('end', function() {
            game.removeClient(socket);
            console.log('A client has disconnected');
        });
        socket.on('error', function(err) {

         console.log(err);
        });
    });

    server.listen(Game1, "localhost", function() {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 6113');
    });

}

//this code is another file as i am calling it by game.clients.push
 addClient: function(client) {
    if (client) {
        self.clients.push(client);
    }
}
```

Yes, it's a clubpenguin emulator

full code: https://github.com/dev3211/bingojs

Comment: add in your code so that folks can figure out whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement socket channels if you are doing this only with NodeJS net.createServer. If you want it simple, you could look for something using express.js, something like this: https://medium.com/factory-mind/websocket-node-js-express-step-by-step-using-typescript-725114ad5fe4